# How to disable .com files in the CLI in Windows 7 32bit?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, 32-bit

I just set up a Windows 7 x86 32bit SP1 enterprise installation,
typed edit (have a costum edit.cmd in my path, in a directory within my user profile) into the CLI, and found out it still has edit.com in C:\windows\system32 (before i was using 64 bit windows)
now I do not want to rearrange my path, but rather disable/delete the edit.com,
how do I do that?

Comment: If you don't want to change `%PATH%`, would it be acceptable to change `%PATHEXT%` to give `.COM`s the least execution precedence?

Comment: but isn't the pathext only used if two files are in the same directory, just differing by the ending?

Comment: I read it as your `edit.cmd` lived in C:\Windows\system32\ along side `edit.com`. My apologies.

Comment: edited to be clearer, thx

Comment: DOS is an obsolete 16-bit operating system, not the name of the text console or the `C:\>` prompt.  There's no DOS in Windows 7 (though `ntvdm` emulates it).

Comment: well yes i meant the emulation, but as i understood it, edit.com is indeed 16-bit, thatswhy it can't be run on 64-bit windows, and I wasn't referring to the CLI as Dos, maybe I wasn't clear in my wording

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually just removing `.com` from pathext does the trick :), thanks @jscott for giving the right hunch, still I'm now curious what has precedence: the `%pathext%` or the `%path%`